# OCCI app crashes when running in debug mode in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio-2005, occi

I'm attempting to get a development environment up and running for developing applications with Oracle C++ Call Interface (OCCI) in Visual Studio 2005.

My system specs are:
OS: Windows 7, 64-bit
Oracle: 11g release 11.2.0.2, 32-bit
Instant Client: BasicLite and SDK version 11.2.0.4 32-bit
Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition version 8.0 with 32-bit tools enabled

I've followed [this guide by Mark Williams](http://oradim.blogspot.dk/2009/07/getting-started-with-occi-windows.html) and I got the example running but ***only*** in release mode. When I switch to debug mode the app will build, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   OCCITest.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  53f5dfdd
Fault Module Name:  KERNELBASE.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.18229
```

The small example program that triggers this error is:

```
#include "employees.h"

using namespace std; 
using namespace oracle::occi;

int main (void) 
{ 
  Employees *pEmployees = new Employees();
  delete pEmployees;
  return 0; 
}

Employees::Employees() 
{      
  user = "hr"; 
  passwd = "hr"; 
  db = "localhost:1521/service_name";
  env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);

  try 
  { 
    con = env->createConnection(user, passwd, db); 
  } 
  catch (SQLException& ex) 
  { 
    cout << ex.getMessage();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  } 
}

Employees::~Employees() 
{ 
  env->terminateConnection (con);
  Environment::terminateEnvironment (env); 
}
```

If I remove all calls to OCCI functionality the application doesn’t crash. That is, this program runs error-free:

```
#include "employees.h"

using namespace std; 
using namespace oracle::occi;

int main (void) 
{ 
  Employees *pEmployees = new Employees();
  delete pEmployees;
  return 0; 
}

Employees::Employees() 
{ 
  user = "hr"; 
  passwd = "hr"; 
  db = "localhost:1521/service_name";
  cout<<"Look at me, I'm running"<<endl;
}

Employees::~Employees() 
{}
```

In the guide Mark mentions that when running in debug mode, the linker should use the library file oraocci11d.lib. However, this file is not included in the Instant Client SDK version 11.2.0.4, so I’m using the input file oraocci11.lib for both the release and debug version.

I'm running out of ideas about how to proceed in solving this problem, and I would greatly appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Oracle DLL receives and/or passes objects such as `std::string` or any other object that either:

1. Manipulates the heap in any way, or
2. The objects could have differing internals between app and DLL,

then you have no choice but to use the correct library to link with.  Otherwise you wind up with binary or heap incompatible objects being passed, which leads to what you're seeing now.

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10764/install.htm#CBHGBBJI

The link above mentions both the debug import library and debug version of the DLL.  Also this is stated at the link:

`Applications that link to MSVCRTD.DLL, a debug version of Microsoft C-Runtime, /MDd compiler flag, should link with these specific OCCI libraries: oraocci11d.lib and oraocci11d.dll.`

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me quite some time to get the debug environment working I figured I'd answer my own question now that I did.

I got a variety of errors throughout the ordeal, but the error that I got most stuck on was an error saying:

> 'The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002).
>   Click OK to close the application.'

Also, I used http://www.dependencywalker.com which repeatedly told me that either `oraocci11d.dll` or a the following list of `dll's` could not be found.

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL 
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

However, what was really missing was for the executable to be able to find `oci.dll`. I'm just mentioning the errors in case someone else runs into these.

**Here is what was needed to make it work:**

First of all, the Instant Client does not contain the `oraocci11d.lib` or `oraocci11d.dll`, so it is necessary to install the full Oracle Client.

Next, the following must be added to the PATH:

- `C:\Program Files\Oracle\11.2.0\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc8`
- `C:\Program Files\Oracle\11.2.0\BIN`

In Visual Studio, select Tools -> Options, unfold 'Projects and Solutions' and select VC++ Directories. In 'Show directories for' under:

- Include Files add `C:\Program Files\Oracle\11.2.0\OCI\include`
- Library files add `C:\Program Files\Oracle\11.2.0\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc8`

In the property page for your project under Configuration Properties -> Linker select Input and under Additional Dependencies add `oraocci11d.lib` (or `oraocci11.lib` for release mode). Then select debug/release mode in the Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

I have a related problem in that I am successfully using oraocci12d.dll/msvcr100d.dll, but this in turn is using oci.dll/**msvcr100.dll**.  ie, oci.dll is not using the debug version of msvcr100.

My program seems to run okay, but any memory leak reporting disappears on exit.