# Compiling OCCI under Windows

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

ALL,

On Windows it is really bad idea to link Debug and Release version of different libraries/binaries as this could cause the crash. The problem is that Windows CRT is different for the Debug and Release.

I'm developing program that will connect to Oracle database perform some queries and then exit. Since the program is still being developed I'm compiling it in the Debug mode.

Now, everywhere I look I can't find a way to download OCCI source code and a way to compile it on Windows as a Debug version. Is it doable? Does Oracle provide a source code for OCCI to being compiled on Windows? Is there a Makefile/MSVC solution that can be used? I prefer latter, but probably can figure out the MSVC solution from the former.

Or maybe the debug version is available somewhere for download?

Thank you.

Comment: Look like Oracle do provide debug version(s) see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429842/occi-app-crashes-when-running-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio-2005/25525686#25525686

Comment: @RichardCritten, thx. I will look it up later tonight.